# 404 not found angular-strap

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I m getting this error when i try to use angular-strap's tooltip. Any ideas why its happening and how to solve it ?

```
GET http://localhost:3000/tooltip/tooltip.tpl.html 404 (Not Found)
```

My code looks like ;

```
var initTooltipAge = function () {
            // Tooltip Validation workaround https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/106
            var inputAge = document.getElementById('input-age');
            if (inputAge) {
                var tooltipAge = this.$tooltip(angular.element(inputAge), {
                    title: "blabla",
                    placement: 'top',
                    trigger: 'manual',
                    style: 'alert'
                });
            }
```

Comment: why are you manipulating the DOM yourself and not using angular directives for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to load the template file:

Load the required javascript libraries (Bootstrap scripts files are not needed).

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/v2.3.7/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/v2.3.7/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
```

Because the template file wasn't loaded, the templateCache is not fed so angularjs will try to fetch the resource, as configured in the directive:

```
templateUrl: 'tooltip/tooltip.tpl.html',
```

Comment: i did exactly that just with bower.. main": [
    "dist/angular-strap.js",
    "dist/angular-strap.tpl.js"
  ],

Comment: You did something wrong.. If the templateCache had `/tooltip/tooltip.tpl.html ` it woudn't try to fetch it again..

Comment: sorry, i fixed it but now i m getting "Cannot read property 'link' of undefined" from this line in the library
 tipElement = $tooltip.$element = compileData.link(tipScope, function(clonedElement, scope) {});